# Domains not loading - server working fine...any ideas?

Tags: dns, nameservers

I run a high volume website and since yesterday it's not working.

My server (for example) **100.0.0.1** is working fine, I can access WHM etc, rootssh no problem....

Yet none of the domains are working, they say cannot find page.

I have my name server setup at Godaddy using domainname.com

Pointing to 3 IPS, **100.0.0.1, 100.0.0.2, 100.0.0.3**

All my domains then have ns1.domainname.com, ns2.domainname.com, ns3.domainname.com
As their Nameserver entries.

This was working fine yesterday, now...nothing.

Any ideas on what I can do? Troubleshoot.

Thank you, I am losing alot of trade as I run an high traffic eCommerce website, so would like to get this fixed as soon as possible.

Comment: Start by dig'ing each of the domains and verifying their configuration is what you expect.  Post one of the domain names and someone can help take a look.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Have you tried using the IP of the server instead of the domain name? Could roll out a DNS issue. You said you can gain root access fine.

- Have you checked your firewall to ensure the correct ports are still open?
- If you run a netstat command to check what type of traffic is occurring. 
  Run this command and then try to access the domain or IP to see if the connection is established or if the service is listening. (watch -n 1 netstat -nat)